# #N/A in sheet when copy pasting between workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I am facing an issue where a certain sheet in the workbook shows #N/A values in exactly 6 rows after the successful copy pasting of all other values from one workbook to another. I simply don't understand why these N/A appear when the cells they appear in are not targeted for the copy pasting.

Example of the problem:

[image]

This is the source sheet. I transfer this data to the other sheet in separate workbook. The result I get is this:

[image]

This is an example code:

```
If (mybook.Name Like "*X1*TOTAL*" Or mybook.Name Like "*X2*Total*") Then
        Var2.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:B4").Value = mybook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B4").Value
End if
```

The full sub routine:

```
If (mybook.Name Like "*66*TOTAL*" Or mybook.Name Like "*66*Total*") Then
        Var2.Sheets("66X").Range("H6:AC43").Value = mybook.Sheets("66X").Range("E9:Z46").Value
        Var2.Sheets("66X").Range("H44:AC77").Value = mybook.Sheets("66X").Range("E48:Z81").Value
        Var2.Sheets("66X").Range("H78:AC133").Value = mybook.Sheets("66X").Range("E83:Z118").Value
        Var2.Sheets("66X").Range("H114:AC119").Value = mybook.Sheets("66X").Range("E120:Z125").Value
        Var2.Sheets("66X").Range("H120:AC127").Value = mybook.Sheets("66X").Range("E127:Z134").Value
```

This is only an extract of the larger original code. For reference and the aim to find a solution, I here provide the code that precedes this code:

```
Sub MergeX()
Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
Dim MyFiles() As String
Dim SourceRcount As Long, FNum As Long
Dim mybook As Workbook
Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long
Dim vTopType As Variant
Dim iTopInset As Integer
Dim iTopDepth As Integer



' Change this to the path\folder location of your files.
    MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D3")
' Add a slash at the end of the path if needed.
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    ' If there are no Excel files in the folder, exit.
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
     'Get destination file name
    Dim Srepfile As String
    MsgBox ("Select AGU Template to populate")
    Srepfile = Application.GetOpenFilename
    Set Var2 = Application.Workbooks.Open((Srepfile), UpdateLinks:=0)

    ' Fill the myFiles array with the list of Excel files
    ' in the search folder.
    FNum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        FNum = FNum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To FNum)
        MyFiles(FNum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    ' Set various application properties.
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
     ' Loop through all files in the myFiles array.
    If FNum > 0 Then
        For FNum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(FNum), UpdateLinks:=0)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are there formulas in the target '5th row' before the value transfer?

Comment: Is there a worksheet_change or workbook_sheetchange event sub procedure in the target 'Shhet2'?

Comment: @Jeeped No there are no formulas in the 5th row of target sheet. Double checked.

Comment: @Jeeped No worksheet_change or workbooksheetchange

Comment: @user3934760 Typically `#N/A`s show up like that when the **destination** (paste) range is larger than the **source** (copy) range. Are you sure there isn't somewhere else in your code that you're writing these ranges to a variable, then transferring values? It doesn't look like you've posted your full subroutine.

Comment: @dwirony In fact there are these cases you are mentioneing and I can provide the full subroutine (or the subroutine for that specific sheet that is failing). The thing is that this shows up AFTER the correct values are pasted into the correct ranges. The N/A are falling outside the ranges.